# Shell Script - Alphabet in code

Tags: bash, shell-script, encryption

I want to create an alphabet where each letter and character has a specific value.

Example:

```
A="99_banana"
a="@_melon"
B="22_GRAPE"
b="orange"
C="Strawberry"
c="life"
@="12399"
!="tv_12"
```

and so on and so forth.

And when I run the script:

encode the sentence:

```
$ ./Encryptfruits -c "Abc!"
output: 99_bananaorangelifetv_12
```

decode the sentence:

```
$ ./Encryptfruits -d "99_bananaorangelifetv_12"
output: Abc!
```

Would anyone have any examples? I searched on google but found nothing

the -c parameter encrypts

the -d parameter decrypts

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something like `sed -e 's/A/99_banana/g' -e 's/a/@_melon/g' -e 's/B/22_GRAPE/g' -e 's/b/orange/g' -e 's/C/strawberry/g' -e 's/c/life/g'` for the encryption?

Comment: FYI, that isn't encryption at all.  It's a simple substitution cipher, and extremely easy to break.  I recommend the book "Applied Cryptography" by Bruce Schneier.  The opening chapters are very accessible and easy to read while also being precisely technically accurate.

Comment: Your example does not work. Are you trying to describe a ceasar cypher with long symbol names.

Answer (score 2):

Not easy in bash, but it can be done using associative arrays.

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A crypt=(
    [A]="99_banana"
    [a]="@_melon"
    [B]="22_GRAPE"
    [b]="orange"
    [C]="Strawberry"
    [c]="life"
    ['@']="12399"
    ['!']="tv_12"
)

encode () {
    local word=$1
    for ((i=0; i<${#word}; ++i)) ; do
        local char=${word:$i:1}
        printf %s ${crypt[$char]}
    done
    printf '\n'
}

declare -A decrypt
for char in "${!crypt[@]}" ; do
    key=${crypt[$char]}
    decrypt[$key]=$char
done

decode () {
    local word=$1
    while [[ $word ]] ; do
        local code
        for code in "${!decrypt[@]}"; do
            if [[ $word == "$code"* ]] ; then
                printf %s "${decrypt[$code]}"
                word=${word#"$code"}
            fi
        done
    done
    printf '\n'
}

encrypted=$(encode 'Abc!')

decode "$encrypted"
```

Note this can break if the encryption of one character is a substring of another character's encryption.

Comment: thank you very much!!! this is amazing, but i have only one doubt How do I add single and double quotes to the array?

Comment: Use `'"'`, `"'"`, or `\'` and `\"`, etc.

Comment: hello, I have one more question, and how would i do to decode ??? ex: decrypted=$(decode '99_bananaorangelifetv_12')

decode "$decrypted"
output "Abc!"

Comment: @Pinguino: To get `Abc!` as the output, use `echo` instead of the second `decode`.

Comment: the right would be to decode, because if I send to a file the output of code can not solve it later

Comment: @Pinguino: I don't understand. It works both ways.

Comment: I want to apologize for my ignorance of not having understood your code, im study shell script just 2 weeks ago 
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
 #! /bin/bash
 declare -A crypt=(
     [A]="99_banana"
     [a]="@_melon"
     [B]="22_GRAPE"
     [b]="orange"
     [C]="Strawberry"
     [c]="life"
     [' ']="space"
     ['@']="12399"
     ['!']="tv_12"
 )

 encode () {
     local word=$1
     for ((i=0; i<${#word}; ++i)) ; do
         local char=${word:$i:1}
         printf %s ${crypt[$char]}
     done
     printf '\n'
 }

 declare -A decrypt
 for char in "${!crypt[@]}" ; do
     key=${crypt[$char]}
     decrypt[$key]=$char
 done

 decode () {
     local word=$1
     while [[ $word ]] ; do
         local code
         for code in "${!decrypt[@]}"; do
             if [[ $word == "$code"* ]] ; then
                 printf %s "${decrypt[$code]}"
                 word=${word#"$code"}
             fi
         done
     done
     printf '\n'
 }

 encrypt=$(encode 'Abc !')

 decrypt=$(decode "$encrypt")

 echo "$encrypt"

 echo "$decrypt"
```

I just added the variables to make it easier to understand